# Submitting HTTP POST only works when CURLOPT_NOBODY is set to 1

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to automate logging into a site via an HTTP form (using POST).  This is the code I have so far.  When a login is successful, the user should get a 302 redirect to another page.  The code below *works* only if I have CURLOPT_NOBODY set to false.  This code outputs https://mytestsite.com/success.jsp, but if I set CURLOPT_NOBODY to 1L, I simply get the url before the redirect (https://mytestsite.com/status.html).  Why is this?

```
int login()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mytestsite.com/login.do");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/home/cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/home/cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "loginId=person1@mytestsite.com&password=mypassword");

    // Disable output from curl_easy_perform
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    char *url;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);

    fprintf(stdout, "#####\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", url);
    fprintf(stdout, "#####\n");

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to print the headers in both cases? Where do they differ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using CURLOPT_HEADER = 1L.  I got HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily ... Location:https://mytestsite.com/status.html, followed by HTTP/1.1 200 OK.  When I set CURLOPT_NOBODY to 1L, I get the same 302 followed by 200 OK but the url that is printed out is still the status.html url.

Comment: I mean *sent* headers.

Comment: With NOBODY = 0, I see POST login.do HTTP/1.1 followed by GET main.html (which is where I want to be).  With NOBODY = 1, I see HEAD login.do HTTP/1.1 followed by HEAD status.html HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what should have happened. `CURLOPT_NOBODY` sets the method to `HEAD`. Try setting the method *after* you set `CURLOPT_NOBODY`.